# Calling hook more then once with diffrent data

Tags: prestashop

I'm trying to use a hook in product_list and need it be called once for each product and somehow pass along the product id, so i can get out relevant data for each product.

Is this possible?

Comment: can u explain it in more detail

Comment: I have a voting module and want to show the current stars for each product in in the product list. So I made a new hook inside the products in the list. But the hook is only called once so it shows the same rating for all products.

Comment: I dont think calling hook is what u shd do, if u are talking about products list in home page prestashop calls a function getProducts in classes/Category.php file to get the products list, that is the function where products are fethed from database, so you may add some code to fetch the votes from database(the votes modules stores the votes in database obviously). find the database add code in classes/Category.php to fetch the data interpret the data in homefeatured.php or whaterver module's php file show them from tpl file

Comment: this way you get the votes of a product along with the products content so you can sort it or arrange it easily I guess